# How to hide an element after clicking outside/body in angular 7 or in css

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an input text, after typing some thing and press space one div 'showit' will show here.Till here its fine but when I click outside anywhere it should hide it.
Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search here" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)">
<div style="border:1px solid;padding:30px;" [hidden]="showit">Show it</div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import Speech from 'speak-tts';
import { RxSpeechRecognitionService, resultList, } from '@kamiazya/ngx-speech-recognition';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],

  providers: [ RxSpeechRecognitionService ]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {  
    showit:any;
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,public service: RxSpeechRecognitionService) {
     }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.showit = true;

} 

onKeyUp($event): void { 
    if ($event.which === 32) {
       this.showit = false;
    } 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add the focusout event to html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search here" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" (focusout)="focusOutFunction()" />
<div style="border:1px solid;padding:30px;" [hidden]="showit">Show it</div>
```

.ts

```
focusOutFunction() {
  this.showit = true;
}
```